# Maximum width of dialog does not affect when width is set to auto

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, width

I'm trying to make the dialog use auto width and height, but only up to a certain width.
But the maxWidth does not take affect till I manually resize the opened dialog.

How can I automatically trigger the check for the width?

Example code: http://jsfiddle.net/yy9Cd/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never done much work with jQuery UI. But here's a fix for what you've got there, obviously I've set the maxWidth to 50px, so change it!

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var myDialog = $("#myDialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    maxWidth: "50px",
    height: 'auto',
});

$("#showDialog").click(function(){
    myDialog.dialog("open");
});

});
```

Comment: The dialog will now use a predefined width and does not take advantage of the maximum width it could use ( = maxWidth). And if I use an unit for the number the maxWidth will be completely ignored.

Comment: Unsure why maxWidth won't set. Why don't you set max-width to your styles for #myDialog in your CSS?

Comment: max-width did the job. It's not as pretty as it could be, but it works now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the CSS max-width property will indeed ensure that the dialog doesn't exceed that width, but the resulting dialog behaves erratically (the overflow isn't reliable, the resize handle may be in the wrong place) because jQuery is ignorant of your setting.  Here's my solution:

```
    var maxWidth = 750;
    var maxHeight = 600;

    var popup = $("<div>" + content + "</div>")
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            title: title,
            hide: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up" },
            height: 'auto',
            width: 'auto',
            maxHeight: maxHeight,
            maxWidth: maxWidth,
            modal: modal,
            buttons: {
                Ok: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });

    var w = popup.dialog("widget").width();
    console.log("w=",w);
    if (w > maxWidth) {
        popup.dialog("option", "width", maxWidth)
        popup.dialog("widget").width(maxWidth);
    }

    var h = popup.dialog("widget").height();
    console.log("h=",h);
    if (h > maxHeight) {
        popup.dialog("option", "height", maxHeight)
        popup.dialog("widget").height(maxHeight);
    }

    w = popup.dialog("widget").width();
    console.log("w2=",w);
    h = popup.dialog("widget").height();
    console.log("h2=",h);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just remove the "width" and "height" properties? http://jsfiddle.net/Ve79f/

Comment: In this case a standard width is used and the dialog will not scale over this automatically. If you have a long text the dialog will be small in width but it will have a big height.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something a little "responsive", I suggest this. Fix a max and min size for your dialog, and ajust it according the window size.

Depending on your dialog, change the values for min or max. Betweend those limits, it scales to 50% of the window size. And it's centered.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        var maxWidth = 500;
        var maxHeight = 300;
        var minWidth = 250;
        var minHeight = 180;

         function diagSize () {
             var wid = $(window).width() * 0.50;
             if (wid > maxWidth) {
                 wid = maxWidth;
             } else if (wid < minWidth) {
                 wid = minWidth
             }
             var hei = $(window).height() * 0.50;
             if (hei > maxHeight) {
                 hei = maxHeight;
             } else if (hei < minHeight) {
                 hei = minHeight
             }
             $("#mydialog").dialog({height: hei, width: wid});
             $("#mydialog").dialog("option", "position", {my: "center", at: "center", of: window});
         }
```

Then your dialog :

```
var mydialog = $("#mydialog).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            closeOnEscape: true,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            buttons: {
                "<spring:message code="action.cancel"/>": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                "<spring:message code="action.next"/>": function () {
                    $.post({
                        url: '/myurl',
                        success: function(data) {

                        },
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

And finally, resize your dialog on 2 case : window resizing and before opening :

```
$(window).resize(diagSize);

$("#btnopenmydialog").on('click', function () {
    diagSize ();
    mydialog.dialog("open");
```

Closing $(document).ready

```
});
```